# NUnit Unit Test has "ExpectedException" but still failing on exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit

I have a unit test that is failing because a `System.ArgumentException` is being thrown, even though I am **expecting** it and it's deliberate behaviour - what have I missed?

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException), ExpectedMessage = "Seconds from midnight cannot be more than 86400 in 010100712386401000000012")]
public void TestParsingCustomReferenceWithInValidSecondsFromMidnight()
{
    // I am expecting this method to throw an ArgumentException:
    CustomReference.Parse("010100712386401000000012");
}
```

I've also tried without the `ExpectedMessage` being set - no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the assertion syntax?

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(
    () => CustomReference.Parse("010100712386401000000012"),
    "Seconds from midnight cannot be more than 86400 in 010100712386401000000012"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the expected message correct? Is that the *exact* same message that CustomReference.Parse(string) throws? For example, it is *not* what is being displayed in the NUnit console.

I wouldn't know another reason why this would not work. What version of NUnit are you using?

Comment: 2.5.2.9222.  Thing is, I've tried it without the expected message, too - same problem. :(

Comment: Hmm strange. It works for me on version 2.4.8. Maybe it is broken in the latest version...

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you do this?

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomReferenceTests
{
    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void TestParsingCustomReferenceWithInValidSecondsFromMidnight()
    {
        // I am expecting this method to throw an ArgumentException:
        CustomReference.Parse("010100712386401000000012");
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException), ExpectedMessage = "Seconds from midnight cannot be more than 86400 in 010100712386401000000012")]
    public void TestParsingCustomReferenceWithInValidSecondsFromMidnightWithExpectedMessage()
    {
        // I am expecting this method to throw an ArgumentException:
        CustomReference.Parse("010100712386401000000012");
    }
}

public class CustomReference
{
    public static void Parse(string s)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Seconds from midnight cannot be more than 86400 in 010100712386401000000012");
    }
}
```