# NUnit NSubstitute not expecting exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I am pretty new to unit testing and NUnit, my case is that a test expecting a simple exception stopped working when I changed from the Ninject NSubstitute mocking kernel adapter to plain NSubstitute for mocking `Returns` purposes.

```
    private IRecordRepository RecordRepositorySeed()
    {
        var repository = Substitute.For<IRecordRepository>();

        record.GetSingleAsync(r => r.Id == "1").Returns(new Task<Record>(() => new Record(...))); // sample record

        return repository;
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(NullReferenceException))]
    public void UnexistantRecord()
    {
        var billingService = new BillingService(RecordRepositorySeed());
        billingService.GenerateBill("5", "test");
    }
```

The test dont pass as it outputs that the test is expecting the `System.NullReferenceException`.

I debugged the tested method and it is actually triggering it:

```
//After a query on record that returns null, this snippet goes on
if (record == null)
{
    //It's reaching this part
    throw new NullReferenceException("record not found");
}
```

I tried these solutions but none of them worked for me:

[NUnit expected exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407765/nunit-expected-exceptions)

[NUnit unit test has ExpectedException but still failing on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928079/nunit-unit-test-has-expectedexception-but-still-failing-on-exception)

The thing is this test was working before I changed the mock to the `Substitute` syntax and I'm unable to figure out what's wrong with this approach.

I'm not sure if it is relevant but the `GenerateBill` method is `async void`

Comment: So the test is failing because NUnit is expecting the exception but it is not being thrown? Does it pass if you remove the `record.GetSingleAsync(...).Returns(...)` line?

Comment: @DavidTchepak Nope, not working that way either, the code it's actually "throwing" the exception, but the test can't recognize it

Comment: If `GenerateBill` is `async void`, maybe the call hasn't completed when the test ends? I'm not sure how the change from the mocking adapter would affect this behaviour, but it might be something worth looking at.

Comment: @DavidTchepak You were right, I made the test async with an await call to GenerateBills and works like a charm ;)